# Can web page launch keyboard of smartphone automatically with <input> and autofocus attribute?

Tags: html, mobile, autofocus, on-screen-keyboard

We can auto-focus a input field when a page is loaded with autofocus attribute of HTML5. Just like this:

```
First name:<input id="firstname" type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Your first name" autofocus="true">
```

My question is, if this  field is the most important task to be done in this page, can I fire the built-in virtual keyboard of smartphone right after this page is loaded?